# Stop validating XML after a certain number of errors

Tags: c#, xml, xml-validation

I have big xml file (150 000 rows), and each row has an error, validation process is very long
How to break validation after a predetermined number of erorrs?

Code sample:

```
MaxValidationErrorCount = 100;

    ....
doc.Validate(ValidationHandler);

....

private void ValidationHandler(object sender, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Severity == System.Xml.Schema.XmlSeverityType.Error)
    {
        CurrValidationErrorCount++;
        _validationErrors += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;

        if (CurrValidationErrorCount >= MaxValidationErrorCount)
            DOBREAKVALIDATIONHERE!!!!
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what Exceptions are for.

```
throw new Exception("Too many errors, man");
```

And if you fear different kinds of errors can occur, [you can make your own type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class TooManyValidationErrorsException : Exception { }

throw new TooManyValidationErrorsException
```

Comment: thanks )
I was looking for matching properties / methods in the validator class ...